# python list.count always returns 0

Tags: python, list, count

I have a lengthy Python list and would like to count the number of occurrences of a single character. For example, how many total times does 'o' occur? I want N=4.

```
lexicon = ['yuo', 'want', 'to', 'sioo', 'D6', 'bUk', 'lUk'], etc.
```

list.count() is the obvious solution. However, it consistently returns 0. It doesn't matter which character I look for. I have double checked my file - the characters I am searching for are definitely there. I happen to be calculating count() in a for loop:

```
for i in range(100): 
    # random sample 500 words 
    sample = list(set(random.sample(lexicon, 500)))
    C1 = ['k']
    total = sum(len(i) for i in sample) # total words
    sample_count_C1 = sample.count(C1) / total
```

But it returns 0 outside of the for loop, over the list 'lexicon' as well. I don't want a list of overall counts so I don't think Counter will work.

Ideas?

Comment: isn't the issue integer division in python 2? try dividing by `float(total)`

Comment: oh : `sample.count(C1)` counts `c` as a word

Comment: I'm not working in Python 2 and it returns 0 absent of the division by total.

Comment: Do you want to count multiple occurrences in a single word or just the words in your sample that contain the char?

Comment: I need to include multiple occurrences in single word, yes.

Comment: @MeC Please see my answer then as it will include multiple occurrences in a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take your `list` (the shortened version you supplied):

```
lexicon = ['yu', 'want', 'to', 'si', 'D6', 'bUk', 'lUk']
```

then we can get the count using `sum()` and a `generator-expression`:

```
count = sum(s.count(c) for s in lexicon)
```

so if `c` were, say, `'k'` this would give `2` as there are two occurances of `k`.

---

This will work in a `for-loop` or not, so you should be able to incorporate this into your wider code by yourself.

---

With your latest edit, I can confirm that this produces a count of `4` for `'o'` in your modified list.

Comment: This code seems to work. Its difficult to interpret what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @quamrana Have you seen their comment? It clarifies the problem somewhat.

Comment: I'm not seeing the clarification myself. Still your code seems to work well at finding all occurrences of a given character through all letters in all words. - OK, I see it now. Come on Stackoverflow! Up vote this answer!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to count the number of occurrences of each character for each word in the list. This is known as a frequency distribution.

Here is a simple implementation using `Counter`

```
from  collections import Counter
lexicon = ['yu', 'want', 'to', 'si', 'D6', 'bUk', 'lUk']
chars = [char for word in lexicon for char in word]
freq_dist = Counter(chars)
Counter({'t': 2, 'U': 2, 'k': 2, 'a': 1, 'u': 1, 'l': 1, 'i': 1, 'y': 1, 'D': 1, '6': 1, 'b': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 1})
```

Using `freq_dist`, you can return the number of occurrences for a character.

```
freq_dist.get('a')
1

# get() method returns None if character is not in dict
freq_dist.get('4')
None
```

Comment: Ok, nice eager algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving zero because `sample.count('K')` will matches `k` as a string. It will not consider `buk` or `luk`.
If u want to calculate frequency of character go like this

```
for i in range(100): 
     # random sample 500 words 
     sample = list(set(random.sample(lexicon, 500)))
     C1 = ['k']
     total = sum(len(i) for i in sample) # total words
     sample_count=sum([x.count(C1) for x in sample])
     sample_count_C1 = sampl_count / total
```